# How can I keep my activity running while a Dialog is open in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm using a Dialog to pick up a text input just so it's easier to see what you're typing, WHILE there's a video playing in the same activity. I want the video to keep playing. When I run the app on an emulator, the video pauses while the dialog is open. However, when I run it on my phone, the video keeps playing.

How can I prevent the dialog from pausing the activity?

EDIT: I'm using YouTubePlayerAPI to play the video, and I just noticed it's logging this message:

> Video playback stopped because of an unauthorized overlay on top of player. The player view is obstructed by another window.

Guess I'll replace the Dialog with a regular EditText for now. Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

Comment: The emulator will never be a better indicator of app behaviour compared to a physical device, so I'd say you are probably good.

Comment: From my understanding of Dialogs, they're actually SUPPOSED to pause your activit (though in this case I don't want them to). So I'm assuming it's a problem with my phone rather than the emulator, and I'd still like to know if there's a way to control this.

Comment: Why can't you leave your video playing until `onStop()`? By the way, the difference is probably due to OS version, and you should treat emulator behavior as canonical.